# How to consume messages from Cloud Pub/Sub with the Messenger component of Symfony and Enqueue adapter?

Tags: php, symfony, google-cloud-pubsub, symfony-messenger, enqueue

### Tools I'm using:

- [Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) 4.1.6
- [Symfony Messenger component](https://github.com/symfony/messenger) 4.1.6
- [Enqueue adapter](https://github.com/php-enqueue/messenger-adapter) 0.1.2
- [Enqueue Google Cloud Pub/Sub Transport](https://github.com/php-enqueue/gps) 0.8.37

---

### My config files:

```
#service.yaml

framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            default: 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f/messages'
            enqueue: 'enqueue://gps'
        default_bus: messenger.bus.commands
        buses:
            messenger.bus.commands: ~
            messenger.bus.events: ~
        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            'App\Message\Command\Store\CreateStore': enqueue
```

.

```
#enqueue.yaml

enqueue:
    transport:
        default: 'gps'
        gps:
            projectId: '%env(GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID)%'
            keyFilePath: '%env(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)%'
```

---

### Sending message / command to a Cloud Pub/Sub queue OK

My message / command `CreateStore` is properly send to Cloud Pub/Sub like this :

```
use App\Message\Command\Store\CreateStore;
use Enqueue\MessengerAdapter\EnvelopeItem\TransportConfiguration;

$command = new CreateStore();
$this->commandBus->dispatch((new Envelope($command))->with(new 
TransportConfiguration(
    ['topic' => 'enqueue.commands']
)));
```

All message/command are in my Cloud Pub/Sub Queue, I can see them and acknowledge them manual via the gcloud Command-Line Tool like this:

`gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull enqueue.commands`

`gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull enqueue.commands --auto-ack`

---

### Consuming messages from a Cloud Pub/Sub queue KO

Now I trying to consume my message by running:

`bin/console messenger:consume-messages enqueue`

The consumer run but nothing is happening.

**What I'm missing to consume my messages available on Cloud Pub/Sub?**

Comment: see my comment on related issue https://github.com/php-enqueue/messenger-adapter/issues/26#issuecomment-429416691